# jQuery Ajax form two submit button in one form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have 2 button in one form. When I click the first or second button, both write example an alert, but the Ajax request doesn't run. I need a form, because i would like to upload images. I don't know what is the problem.

page.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Ajax two submit in one form</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="animal-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <span>Name:</span>
    <input type="text" name="animalname" id="animalname">

    <span>Image:</span>
    <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile">

    <button type="submit" name="publish" id="publish">Publish</button>
    <button type="submit" name="save" id="save">Save</button>

</form>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#animal-upload').on('submit', function() {

    return false;

});

$('#publish').click(function() {

    alert("Test");

});

$('#save').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({

        url: "animal-upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {

            alert(data);

        }

    });

});

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

animal-upload.php

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");

$status = '';

$animalname = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST["animalname"]);

if ($_FILES['imagefile']['name'] != '') {

    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES['imagefile']['name']));
    $allowed_type = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

    if (in_array($extension, $allowed_type)) {

        $new_name = rand() . "." . $extension;
        $path = "animals/" . $new_name;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'], $path)) {

            mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO animals (animalname,image) VALUES ('".$animalname."','".$path."')");

            $status = 'Successful!';

        }

    } else {

        $status = 'This is not image file!';

    }

} else {

    $status = 'Please select image!';

}

echo $status;

?>
```

Comment: Try specifying your dataType. Since you're not specifying, it's just guessing.

Comment: What is the error message because the ajax request runs successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and errors I found the script work if you change this line :

```
data: new FormData($("#animal-upload")[0]),
```

Because that selects the form object.

You may consider some security tips :

- Don't divulge your password in public
- Don't let your database users connect without passwords
- Make a user with strict minimum privileges just for the purpose to connect to your database from PHP scripts (it's called the principle of least privileges)
- Rename your uploaded file

For the file upload to work :

- Make sure you have the right permissions on the directory pointed by
  `upload_tmp_dir` in php.ini file
- You may need to check that your file size doesn't exceed the `memmory_limit` directive too

good luck,